# Which NSXPCConnection related objects do I have to retain myself?

Tags: cocoa, ipc, xpc

I cannot find any hint in the docs regarding object lifecycle management.

1. In the XPC service, do I have to keep a strong reference to the `NSXPCListener`, or does the `resume` call take care of this effectively?

   I'm using Swift and a connection creation object to get most of the stuff out of the `main.swift` file:

   ```
   // main.swift
   if let dependencies = Dependencies().setUp() {
       // Actually run the service code (and never return)
       NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().run()
   }
   ```

   I have the hunch that the `dependencies` object (which creates the `NSXPCListener` during set up) should keep a strong reference to the listener object. But the `resume` method is said to work like operation queues.
2. Conversely, does the client *need* to keep the `NSXPCConnection` around?
3. In the XPC service, upon incoming connection, does setting `exportedObject` retain that object for the duration of the connection, or do I have to keep a strong ref to it myself?
4. Consequently: When multiple connections come in, should I maintain a list of `exportedObject`s?
5. In either the client of service, should I obtain a `remoteObjectProxy` once and keep it around, or should I obtain a proxy object anew for every call?

   My partcular XPC service is a launchd process running all the time, not a one-off thing, and the client app itself might run for a few hours in the background, too. I worry whether it's safe to keep a proxy object to the background service for a potentially long-running communication.

   If background services crash, launchd is said to restart them. Now if my service was a "launch on demand" service instead, will message calls to proxy objects issue a relaunch if necessary, will obtaining a proxy object do, or will only reconnecting achieve that?

Thanks for helping me sort this out!